# Cannot compile class into a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, compilation

I'm new to Java and I want to figure out how to compile my Java code into a jar file. I've figured out how to compile my file into a class file, but when I try to run the compilation command it gives me this error.

```
jar : The term 'jar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.     
At line:1 char:1
jar cvf Test.jar *
+ ~~~
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jar:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The tutorial I used told me to run this command in the terminal.

`jar cvf Count.jar Count.class`

However, all this does is throw the aforementioned error. Again, I am new to Java, so perhaps there's something I'm missing.

Comment: It seems not to find the `jar` command which should be in the directory with `javac`, the JDK directory.

Comment: The full JDK is not in your path.  Try running the command under cmd.exe instead of power shell for a more common error message.

Comment: @strom that is it. Maybe an IDE is advisable?

Comment: It worked when I used the cmd. Thanks @Strom.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Strom for the answer. I was using the command in Visual Studio Code's terminal rather than the CMD.

Comment: I suggest you revamp this Answer to be more descriptive and detailed, to be helpful to people in the future.